# Setting up CakePhp on localhost

Tags: cakephp

I have "inheirted" a CakePHP site. I have the dropped the sites folder into my localhost and setup the database configuration. It seems to be loading the views, but the .css and images are not getting loaded and the links are pointing directly to localhost for example.

```
localhost/categorys
```

Instead of

```
localhost/mysite/categorys
```

Is there a configuration I need to set to make sure everything is pointed to correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your index.php file in your app/webroot directory.

Scroll down to the part that says:

```
/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
        define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
    }
```

and make sure the paths point to the places the comments say they should point to.

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up putting it the root of my localhost.